# How do you update a variable in shell script?

Tags: shell, makefile, variable-assignment, bin

I have a Makefile that includes a bldconfig.mk at the top and defines a variable that I want to be able to update. `VERSION` is made up of variables (`MAJOR`,`MINOR`,`SUBMINOR`) from the bldconfig.mk. I want to add the letter "d" at the end of `VERSION` conditionally.

```
include bldconfig.mk
VERSION = $(MAJOR).$(MINOR).$(SUBMINOR)
```

I currently am using the code below to update the `VERSION` variable in the conditional below, but it does not update.

```
.PHONY: drive
drive:
    if [ $(debug) = "on" ]; then\
        VERSION = "${VERSION} d"; \
        echo "version: ${VERSION}"; \
    fi
```

I used the echo command to check to see if the VERSION variable is updated. When I build this project, the echo statement shows that it is not updated. This is the output:

> /bin/sh: VERSION: command not found

> version: 6.0.80

I have also tried to concatenate with different methods to no avail such as:

```
VERSION+=" d"
```

Comment: UPDATE: The reason why it says "command not found" is because there was space around the =. It should be VERSION="${VERSION} d". But is still does not update the variable.

Comment: Make variables are not shell variables, nor the other way around.  It follows that you cannot use the shell code in a recipe to modify a `make` variable. (And that's not the only reason.)

Comment: (1) Please don't explain bug fixes to the code posted in a **comment**, but update your question accordingly. (2) The command `X = Y` executes the program `X` with the two parameters `=` and `Y`, which explains the error message. (3) Technically speaking, variables can not be updated, but reassigned, and this is what you are doing correctly.  (4) A `make` process has no access to the variables of a different process, which means that it does not know the bash variables, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Shell requires assignment symbol to be directly after the variable:

```
VERSION="${VERSION} d"
```

Otherwise it gets interpreted as a command.

(Please have subsequent problems posted as separate questions.)